# Установить размытие android shape

Tags: android, listview, shape

Ниже приведет код фона элемента списка c тенью, но тень получается четкая, можно ли как то сделать размытие тени?

item_shape_baground.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item >
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:right="1dp" android:left="1dp" android:bottom="2dp">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
                <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Comment: ну так а кто мешает добавить полупрозрачный цвет тени?

Comment: зачем layer-list для этого? он будет view ку полностью смещать. 
Существует куча способов, чтоб настроить тень, android:elevation="5dp" не подходит?

Comment: @ermak0ff а как это можно сделать в xml

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei это свойство нужно в элементе списка прописывать или в самом списке?

Comment: @KirillStoianov  да хоть так захардкодить, без разницы                        <solid android:color="#40000000" />

Comment: вобщем я попробывал, это не то. в Photoshop это называется "transparency"  а мне надо свойство "blur"

Comment: @KirillStoianov а ну так заблюрить просто так не получится)

Comment: @ermak0ff а какие есть варианты?

Comment: @KirillStoianov на хабре почитайте, может поможет чем http://habrahabr.ru/post/215077/